# error in displaying table last column in Beamer

Tags: beamer, longtable

Using the following code, I can not figure out why the last column text is not displayed when using the code

```
\centering {\textcolor{black} {\bf receptors}}`
```

giving the error message

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
{\ifnum 0=`}\fi \penalty \@M \futurelet \@let@token \LT@@h...
l.38     \end{frame}
?
```

but it only could be displayed when using the code

```
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\parbox {.29\textwidth}{\centering {\textcolor{black} {\bf receptors}}}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{\bf Types of ...}
\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}[c]{1.\textwidth}
{
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}[!htp]{|m{.16\textwidth}|m{.16\textwidth}|m{.28\textwidth}|}\hline
\centering {\textcolor{black} {\bf hello}} & 
\centering {\textcolor{blue} {\bf hello}}\\
{\textcolor{green} {\bf hello}} &
%\centering {\textcolor{black} {\bf receptors}}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\parbox {.29\textwidth}{\centering {\textcolor{black} {\bf receptors}}}}
\\ \hline
\centering {\textcolor{black} {\bf hello}} & 
\centering {\textcolor{blue} {\bf hello}}\\
{\textcolor{green} {\bf hello}} &
\\ \hline
\centering {\textcolor{black} {\bf hello}} & 
\centering {\textcolor{blue} {\bf hello}}\\
{\textcolor{green} {\bf hello}} &
\\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should not use deprecated font commands such as `\bf`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc

Comment: The code might be ugly, but compiles fine for me without error.

Comment: did you use \centering {\textcolor{black} {\bf receptors}} instead of using \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\parbox {.29\textwidth}{\centering {\textcolor{black} {\bf receptors}}}}

Comment: Please make a MWE that actually reproduces the error.

Comment: just uncomment the line \centering {\textcolor{black} {\bf receptors}},  and  comment the line \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\parbox {.29\textwidth}{\centering {\textcolor{black} {\bf receptors}}}}

Comment: I removed completely all \bf codes, and I got the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code seems unnecessarily complicate, I'd write the table like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Types of ...}
\begin{table}
    \bfseries
    \begin{tabular}{|C{.16\textwidth}|C{.16\textwidth}|C{.28\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        hello & \textcolor{blue}{hello} \textcolor{green}{hello} & receptors\\ \hline
        hello & \textcolor{blue}{hello} \textcolor{green}{hello} & \\ \hline
        hello & \textcolor{blue}{hello} \textcolor{green}{hello} & \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Please note the following changes:

- `\bf` is deprecated and should no longer be used.
- You should not use formatting instructions in arguments of macros like `\frametitle`. If you want to change the font, use `\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}`
- nesting a `table`, a `minipage`, a group, a `center` environment and a `longtable` is really overkill. Tables are centred by default in beamer, and the `minipage` and the group don't do anything useful. Also you are not using any special features of the `longtable`
- Beamer does not have floats, it makes no sense to specify floating specifier
- `\centering` is a switch, it does not take arguments.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please tell me what was wrong in the code I used.

Comment: @Hany `\centering` redefines what ``\\`` means, which also explains why it is only a problem in the lat column. The trick is also using `\arraybackslash` which reverts the table/array meaning of ``\\`` as the ender of a row\

Comment: @samcarter Thank you very much for your explanation.

Comment: @samcarter Please just one comment. I used m option to vertically align text inside cells; but your fine code does not allow this. Text is still top aligned.

Comment: @Hany If you look at my code, you'll see that I also use the m column. Also as you can see in my screenshot the text is not top aligned!

Comment: @samcarter I am very sorry. When I applied your code to my original document, in which the table is much more complicated than my MWE, I missed removing one of the old \bf codes, which resulted in that error. Can your code be adjusted to decrease a little bit the horizontal spacing between text and cell boundaries.

Comment: @Hany Adjusting the space between the content and the lines is a different question.