# Adjusting spacing between text and cell boundaries in tables in Beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

Using the following code from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453930/error-in-displaying-table-last-column-in-beamer), how can the spacing between the text and cell margins (vertically and horizontally) be adjusted.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Types of ...}
\begin{table}
    \bfseries
    \begin{tabular}{|C{.16\textwidth}|C{.16\textwidth}|C{.28\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    hello & \textcolor{blue}{hello} \textcolor{green}{hello} & receptors\\ \hline
    hello & \textcolor{blue}{hello} \textcolor{green}{hello} & \\ \hline
    hello & \textcolor{blue}{hello} \textcolor{green}{hello} & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\tabcolsep` for more horizontal space (see: [Adding space between columns in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16519/134144)) and `\arraystretch` for more vertical space (see: [Increase LaTeX table row height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159257/134144)) should work. You could for example use `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{20pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}`

Comment: The best solution to this problem is to simply ditch all these lines. See e.g. http://betterposters.blogspot.com/2012/08/the-data-prison.html

Comment: Thank you, but this solution add spacing between columns, not between text and cell boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

see, if the following solution can help you:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}

    \usepackage{cellspace,                  % for adding vertical space around cells' contents
                tabularx}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{7pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{7pt}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \addparagraphcolumntypes{C}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\frametitle{Types of ...}
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}  % for vertical centering of X cell contents
    \setlength\tabcolsep{12pt}              % increase horizontal space around cell         \begin{table}
\bfseries
\begin{tabularx}{0.75\linewidth}{|*{2}{>{\hsize=0.25\hsize}SC|}
                                       >{\hsize=0.50\hsize}C|
                                } \hline
hello & \textcolor{blue}{hello} \textcolor{green}{hello} & receptors\\ \hline
hello & \textcolor{blue}{hello} \textcolor{green}{hello} &          \\ \hline
hello & \textcolor{blue}{hello} \textcolor{green}{hello} &          \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
```

[image]